# Image cannot be converter from byte array

Tags: c#

I have block code:

```
        Image x = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Tung\Pictures\Untitled.png");
        ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(x, typeof(byte[]));

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("textfile.txt");
        string base64String =  System.Convert.ToBase64String(xByte,0,xByte.Length);
        sw.WriteLine(base64String);
        sw.Close();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("textfile.txt");
        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        sr.Close();

        File.WriteAllBytes("F:\\YourFile1.png", byteArray);
        File.WriteAllBytes("F:\\YourFile2.png", xByte);
```

after run, YourFile1.png can not display and YourFile2.png display ok. I do not understand. Can you help me?

Comment: Hint #1: `System.Convert.ToBase64String`

Comment: Can you say more?

Comment: What does that method do? Just check the `YourFile1.png` contents with some text editor and the problem would be obvious.

Comment: Right!. they are different. Thanks. So what should I do?. please help me!

Comment: You have read binary image contents, encoded it in base64, wrote to file. To then you have read the file and treated it as binary. 3 steps to store, 2 steps to load. Don't you see something missing?

Comment: Right!.Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
```

The `line` variable here is a base64 encoded string, where each character represents 3/4 of a byte (6 bits to encode 64 possible values). But `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` looks at each character in your string and produces a full byte for each character (more for non-ascii characters, but you won't have those here). It's not decoding the base64 data at all. You need to do this:

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(line);
```

Comment: 1/4, since a byte has 256 possible values and base64 characters have 64 each... but it was a slip of the keyboard, and I was already saving the fix as you posted.

Comment: It depends on what you measure it with. It is 6 bits of 8 => 3/4 (in terms of space)

Comment: Actually we both are: I like that it is both 3/4 in terms of space and 1/4 in terms of representable values :-)